# Polymer - How to specify version number for specific elements?

Tags: polymer, bower, paper-elements, core-elements

I'm pretty new to Bower.  In my bower.json file, I have Polymer, core-elements, and paper-elements set to version 0.5.4.  However, I want to set core-icons as version 0.5.2 while keeping all the other elements as 0.5.4.  How can I do this?  Here is my bower.json code:

```
{
    "name": "website",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#~0.5.4",
        "core-elements": "Polymer/core-elements#~0.5.4",
        "paper-elements": "Polymer/paper-elements#~0.5.4"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `"core-icons": "Polymer/core-icons#~0.5.2"`?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Will try.  I'll tell you how it goes :D

Comment: @JamesDonnelly  Afraid it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
bower install --save polymer/core-icons#0.5.2
```

or add in bower.json

```
"core-icons": "polymer/core-icons#0.5.2"
```

then run `bower install`. It works for me.